# MySQL select mixing two fields as a single value

Tags: mysql

I have a table containing prefixed number phones: prefix is on `cm_prefix` field and phone number on `cm_phone` field.

On the other hand, I have a table with the full number (prefix and phone) on a single field named `cr_phone`.

When I try to select all matching numbers I get no results, as I must be making a syntax error combining `cm_prefix` with `cm_phone`:

```
SELECT * FROM ws_campreplies JOIN ws_campmsg WHERE cr_phone=cm_prefix+cm_phone
```

How must be ***cr_phone=cm_prefix+cm_phone*** be fomruled?

Comment: Try `SELECT * FROM ws_campreplies JOIN ws_campmsg WHERE cr_phone=CONCAT(cm_prefix,cm_phone)` second add ON clause

Comment: Thank you! Please add as an answer in order to tick you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For concatenating string use `CONCAT` instead of `+` like:

```
SELECT *
FROM ws_campreplies
JOIN ws_campmsg
  ON cr_phone=CONCAT(cm_prefix,cm_phone)
```

Comment: Thank you, I'll tick in 10 minutes

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM ws_campreplies 
JOIN ws_campmsg on cr_phone = concat(cm_prefix, cm_phone)
```